# (DDD) Retrieve entity stored in multiple databases

Tags: architecture, repository, domain-driven-design

I'm embarking on a new (dotNet Core) WebAPI, in which some data is to be read from the application's database (using EFCore), and some from Microsoft Graph. In particular, a person's email address and full name can be retrieved from Graph, and specific to the app, we want to know when the person was registered with the application, and when that person last logged in. In terms of Domain Driven Design, I'd say that all these properties belong to an entity `User`. However, I'm struggling with how to populate such a User entity. Is there any guidance on how to populate an object whose information is stored in two different databases / services? Note that there is no need to update the information in Graph.

I'm considering 3 options:

1. The simplest option is to store the entities directly in the database. With a `UserRepository` I can first get the record from the database and subsequently supplement it with data retrieved data from Graph.
2. The more elaborate options is to have classes that correspond to the database structures, and have the `UserRepository` fetch data from the various databases / services, and subsequently map that to a real Entity. The benefit of this option is that the Entities are totally disconnected from the database, but there is a lot of work going into mapping entities back and forth to database records.
3. The last option that I've thought of is to treat app related user information (stored in the database) and identity related information (in Graph) as two different objects. The burden on combining these two pieces of data would then fall on consumer of my API.

What would you have done given a limited budget and tight deadlines?

Comment: The fact that your data is spread across multiple databases is a Big Hint[tm] that you aren't modeling a single domain entity, but rather multiple entities that can be joined (for reporting purposes) via a common correlation identifier.

Comment: How volatile is the data?  As in, is it volatile enough to be a factor in the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit I'm not really a conscious follower of DDD.

You could have a `UserAppUsageHistory` entity or similar, put the data in there (**your option 3**). You'd just need a sensible way for API consumers to join them (`UserId`?).  Assuming that `UserAppUsageHistory` data updates more frequently than `User` data, this *might* work well.

Just as an aside, from an API consumer perspective you really want to ask the consumers what they want (e.g. co-design), since that's the best way to get to an API which is good for it's consumers.

> (**your option 2**) ...but there is a lot of work going into mapping entities back and
> forth to database records

Sounds a bit concerning from the API consumer usability perspective, if it's hard for you it won't be easier for them.

**Option 1 & 3** have a latency issue - sure you can serve data off your local copy - but it is up-to-date?  Maybe that doesn't matter?  And with option 1 you've only got a much more limited amount of data (how fit for purpose is that?).

A key difference between 1 & 3 is how likely is it that the history data's structure will change?  Because whenever it changes it's potentially going to impact everything that `User` touches.

It comes down to a trade-off between which set of problems you prefer to have, along with which benefits.

Another advantage of option 3, is that because they are loosely-coupled, you can always farm out the gathering of that data to some background process that keeps known user data updated, within whatever limits you deem sensible.  You'd may need something special/additional for newly-added users though.

> What would you have done given a limited budget and tight deadlines?

It depends.  Creating technical debt sucks, but sometimes its unavoidable.  Option 3 sounds safer and more flexible long-term, if you can cope with the extra work.

Important considerations are:

- Nature of the data's structure/schema (how much, how complex)?  The more complex -> use separate entity.
- Likelihood of that structure/schema changing?  If likely -> keep away from `User`.
- How volatile the data is (how often do records update)?
- How critical is it that the data you have is current?

Regarding those last two: devise a strategy to deal with fetching the data and see if that influences your decision around your question.  If volatile, option 3 sounds better to me.

Lastly, have you considered **LazyLoad** (pattern)?  It doesn't directly solve your question, but if you can get the History data separately then it makes initial `User` instantiation simpler and quicker because you just load in the core `User` data at runtime, and only load in the history data if/when it's explicitly asked for.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest as a general guideline, is that persistence technology (or combination of) is an implementation detail hidden behind repositories.

As per DDD, the `UserRepository` should return a Domain Object, in this case a `User` aggregate. This rules out **Option 3**.

Regarding **Options 1 & 2**, if I understand correctly, you are considering whether the repository should implement mapping or store entities directly in the DB.

I would say that ideally you want to have the mapping. That way you have complete isolation between your domain objects and your persistence structure.  This should provide more flexibility to your codebase.

However, if you are on a limited budget & tight schedule, going without the mapping should be fine. However you should try to ensure that the mapping can be added inside the repository in the future, without affecting the repository API (=without affecting any code using the repository).